# didEndDisplayingCell isn't called when playing video using ios webView

Tags: ios, webview, youtube

I am playing youtube video using UIWebView.
When disappear cell , I am going to stop playing video.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
       didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
       forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

This delegate is working well for another cell but not while playing video using webview..
How can I detect to disappear cell on screen?
If anyone know about that , Please let me know that.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

was having the same issue, but reading the documentation it clearly states "Tells the delegate that the specified cell was removed from the collection view" , which in this case doesn't happen (maybe due to some strong reference)

to solve the issue I shifted the pausing/stop code to

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
   willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell
forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and retrieve the previous cell in it by some changes to indexPath